# Get li aligned in the same line

Tags: html, css, html-lists, positioning

How do I get that search box in the same line, right after the **Product Selector** item?

```css
#header_nav_bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 0em;
  padding-right: 26em;
  padding-bottom: 0em;
  padding-left: 32em;
  font-family: serif;
  font: century;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
}
#header_nav_bar li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 1.8em;
}
#header_nav_bar a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  display: inline;
}
#header_nav_bar a.current {
  color: text-decoration: none;
}
#header_nav_bar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  font: century;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
container-1 input#search {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10;
  background: #eff3fb;
  border: none;
  font-size: 8pt;
  float: right;
  color: #63717f;
  background-image: url('images/search1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
#header_nav_bar li.container-1 {
  border-right: none;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<nav id="header_nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Find.html">FIND BY CATEGORY</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="Brands.html">OUR BRANDS</a> 
    </li>
    <li class="logo">
      <a href="logo.html">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="60" height="60">
      </a>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Product Selector.html">PRODUCT SELECTOR</a>
    </li>
    <li class="container-1">
      <!--<div class="container-1">
                                                  <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>-->
      <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="search" />


    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline-block` to this css class and see if it works.

```
container-1 input#search {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10;
  background: #eff3fb;
  border: none;
  font-size: 8pt;
  float: right;
  color: #63717f;
  background-image: url('images/search1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: don't know if you already saw, but I answered one minute after your comment

Comment: Thanks for the help boys! I appreciate it! I tried the longer answer and modified the code a little and it works beautifully. I didn't try Nguyen suggestion because the other one worked but nevertheless I appreciate it.